# Where to put AngularJS model logic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an app that deals with Shape POCO objects. I retrieve these shape objects from an angular js ShapeService. Shapes can have a width and height, and can also be told to maintain their aspect ratio. To do this then, I need to know when the width or height has changed so that I can auto change the other to maintain its ratio. The question is, where do I put this logic? It would make sense to me that this logic belongs to the Shape object itself, but I'm not sure how I get the shape obect to enforce it.

Should the Shape object be able to enforce this rule within itself? if so how? Should it be the services responsibility? how would I do this without having the service $watch my controllers model? Some other way I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to have the `Shape` object enforce it by itself. After all, that is what a Shape is supposed to do, as you indicated.

The problem is how to get the Shape to enforce it. That depends on what Shape is and how it is.

If Shape is a POJSO (Plain Old JS Object), then there is no way to enforce it.

```
shapeA = {width:10,height:20,enforce:true}
```

There is *nothing* preventing something from doing `shapeA.width = 20` and saying, "Haha! I ignored your enforcement!

If you are working in a guaranteed es5 environment where you can use getters and setters / `Object.defineProperty`, then you can do interesting things like enforcing the aspect ratio, since changing one as `shapeA.width = 20` will call an underlying method in the object, which can then enforce the aspect ratio (or anything else, for that matter).

If you cannot rely on ES5 setters, and you need to enforce it, you can set the object to only have explicit setters

```
shapeA = {getWidth:function(){...}, setWidth: function(){...}, /* etc. */ }
```

Which is ugly, but works.

You could also do it in the ShapeService, again via functions.

You could allow it free-form like in the first example, but enforce behaviour at save time. This isn't great, since errors can be on screen for a while until it is saved, but it works.

Last, you could use the controller and `$scope.$watch`, but I am no enamoured of the solution. How many of these Shapes will you watch? And this logic really doesn't exist in the controller.

I wish there were a cleaner answer. Only support es5 environment? :-)

Comment: I was starting to go down the $scope.$watch route but likewise didn't like it. It either meant scattering logic into places it doesn't belong, or having my service have a dependency on the scope so it could watch for changes (if I didn't want to go down the save() route you mentioned), but again, a bit bluh!. It's moments like these just sticking everything on $rootScope starts to look attractive :)

Comment: You definitely don't want your service depending on scope. It's a bad place to be, and requires some convoluted stuff, bad dependencies, and messed up unit testing. I had a lot of stuff on `$rootScope` in an app too, but it made it difficult, started to regret it, and slowly ripped them out. You almost wish angular had a `Service.$watch` in addition to `$scope.$watch`, or some sort of generic watch service to watch objects. I imagine the performance hit would be awful.

Comment: I went the defineProperty route and it seems to be working a treat. So much more logical, and no unnecessary $watch statements. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Glad it worked. Just remember that it will only work in es5, so node and the browsers listed http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/ although there are other lists. Personally, I don't like `$watch` and try to avoid it as well.